# Regex X and/or Y

Tags: java, php, regex

Consider the following regular expression, where `X` and `Y` are *any* regex.

```
XY|YX|X|Y
```

This regex tests for `X` and/or `Y`, but has to double-check expressions if the "and" clause is not found.

What is the best way to match `X` **and/or** `Y`?

Comment: @DevZer0 That matches the absence of both `X` and `Y`.

Comment: What about `YX`? Or is it just `X` or `Y` or `XY`?

Comment: then define a class `[XY]`

Comment: @DevZer0 `X` and `Y` are *any* regex.  In the case that they are single characters, that would work, but I'm looking for the general case solution.

Comment: Uhwell, `X?Y`... `X` zero or one time, followed by Y

Comment: @fge That doesn't match `X` or `YX`.

Comment: What about something simple like `/XY?|YX?/`?

Comment: Well, that is not what your question is!

Comment: Yep, @Craig has the answer here; note however that your two regexes must not have any common match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `/XY?|YX?/` should work to match each of the four situations  you listed. This is limited however, as if the regex you use have a common match, you may get unexpected results.

> With limited information, comes limited solutions

If this is an issue, perhaps add more requirements to the question.

*Explanation:*

The first half will attempt to match the `X` regex then will attempt to match the `Y` regex `0` or `1` times. If the `X` regex fails, then it will try the second half; which will attempt to match the `Y` regex then will attempt to match the `X` regex `0` or `1` times.

Answer (score 1):

`[XY]+` to get any number of Xs and Ys (so includes `XYYXYX`, etc).

Or...

`[XY]{1,2}` to select 1-2 Xs and Ys (which only includes your 4 examples).

Comment: That allows `XX` and `YY`.

Comment: Character classes will not work (as discussed in the comments), because `X` and `Y` represent *anything*, not just a character.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement of `X and/or Y` how about this regex:

```
(?:(?=.*?X)|(?=.*?Y))(X|Y)
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/K36HjXzHLF

Comment: This matches the entire line when `X` and/or `Y` are present, rather than just the `X` and/or `Y` portion itself.

Comment: It matches the line if X and/or Y are present, line won't be matched if both X and Y are not present.

Comment: In case you don't want to match full line you can use regex as in this link: http://www.rubular.com/r/K36HjXzHLF

Comment: That is now essentially equivalent to simply `X|Y` as far as what it matches.  An occurrence of `XY` should be matched like so, but your regex matches them separately as `X` and `Y`.